# Matrix of 10x10 with the same values on principal diagonal and anti-diagonal are the same and for the otherwise is zero whit for in R

Tags: r

I would create in R a square matrix where the values on main diagonal and anti-diagonal is the same. It's 2. The otherwise value is 0.

I would use the function "for" but I have no idea how to apply it.

This is that i would, but the way is wrong because i must use the function "for"

```
a <- matrix(0 , 10,10)
diag(a) <- 2
a <- data.frame(a)
a <- as.matrix(data.frame(lapply(a , rev)))
diag(a) <- 2
colnames(a) <- NULL
a
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
#>  [2,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
#>  [3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
#>  [4,]    0    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0     0
#>  [5,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0
#>  [6,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]    0    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
#>  [9,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
#> [10,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
```

Comment: Without the `for` loop this is a bit simpler: `diag(m) <- diag(m[rev(1:10), ]) <- 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's possibly the quickest way to do it with a for-loop.

```r
m <- matrix(0, 10, 10)

for(i in 0:9) m[11*i+1] <- m[10+i*9] <- 2

m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
#>  [2,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
#>  [3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
#>  [4,]    0    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0     0
#>  [5,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0
#>  [6,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]    0    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
#>  [9,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
#> [10,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
```

This works because a matrix can be indexed with a single number representing the entries in column 1 (1:10), then column 2 (11:20) and so on. The diagonal starts at position 1 and repeats every 11 entries. The anti-diagonal starts at 10 and repeats every 9 entries.

If this is a homework assignment, your teacher will probably want you to use the [row, column] notation for subsetting and use nested for loops, so you would be safer submitting this:

```r
m <- matrix(0, 10, 10)

for(i in 1:10) {
  for(j in 1:10) {
    if(i == j || i == 11 - j)  {
      m[i, j] <- 2
    }
  }
}

m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
#>  [2,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
#>  [3,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
#>  [4,]    0    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0     0
#>  [5,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0
#>  [6,]    0    0    0    0    2    2    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]    0    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    2    0     0
#>  [9,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    2     0
#> [10,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2
```

Though it would be fun watching your teacher getting their head around the first version...

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: For the single loop, `for(i in 1:10) m[i, i] <- m[11-i, i]<- 2` is a bit easier to follow.